# call js function multiple times from one click

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript so there might be a simple solution to my problem.
I have made a xml-file where i store information about images i want to add to my webpage, these have tags added.
I have found a js-function which will hide/show the images by an on-click link, just as i want.
however i would like to show all images with a certain tag at one click and thats where the problem is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) 
{
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) 
     {
     item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
     }
}
function ClassTag(Name) 
{
 var TagNameArrayJS = <?php echo json_encode($TagNameArray); ?>;
 var TagArrayJS = <?php echo json_encode($TagArray); ?>;
 var PhotoIdArrayJS = <?php echo json_encode($PhotoIdArray); ?>;

 var aa = 0;
 var bb = 0;
    while(aa < TagNameArrayJS.length)
    {
        if(TagNameArrayJS[aa] == Name)
        {
            while(bb < TagArrayJS[aa].length)
            {
                unhide(PhotoIdArrayJS[TagArrayJS[aa][bb]]);
                bb = bb + 1;
            }
        }
    aa = aa + 1;
    }                                           
}
</script>
```

output:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function unhide(divID) 
 {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) 
     {
     item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
     }
 }
 function ClassTag(Name) 
 {
 var TagNameArrayJS = ["All","Anders","Hanna","Church","Party"];
 var TagArrayJS = [[0,1,2],[0],[0,1,2],[0,2],[1]];
 var PhotoIdArrayJS = ["JPG001","JPG002","JPG003"];

 var aa = 0;
 var bb = 0;
    while(aa < TagNameArrayJS.length)
        {
        if(TagNameArrayJS[aa] == Name)
            {
                while(bb < TagArrayJS[aa].length)
                    {
                        unhide(PhotoIdArrayJS[TagArrayJS[aa][bb]]);
                        bb = bb + 1;
                    }
            }
        aa = aa + 1;
        }                                           
}
</script>
```

the html:

```
<a href="javascript:ClassTag('hanna');">Hanna</a>
```

I wrote a new function "ClassTag" to call the unhide function at the images i wanted. 
TagNameArray has the name of the tags, to compare with the called.
TagArrayJS has in each position an array with which image-number is to be called.
PhotoIdArrayJS has the Id which is used in the unhide function.

So the question, how do i write a function which uses these data to call my unhide function the number of times i want?

/Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery if possible - it will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. jQuery is the answer to your problems. The nested for loop you've got going on there is fun to look at, but such a pain to maintain. Invest just a little time learning jQuery and you'll love it.

Comment: it probably would, I would like to learn more script though so i though I would try making my own so that i could understand what i'm doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `while(bb < TagArrayJS.length)` to `while(bb < TagArrayJS[aa].length)`.

Furthermore, as other users said, consider learning jQuery because it will simplify the code.

Comment: I will, just feels like i have to get to know javascript better too.. done the change (thx for the correction), still doesn't work though..

Comment: Ok, realized how bad I am at debugging code and not being consequent!
The function call has the "Name" variable with a small case starting letter, the compared string does not..

Sorry for the trouble - I will start looking at jQuery, i promise - Thanks for all the help!